# Yet another linker issue

Tags: c++, linker, header-files

I'm having a linking issue with a basic C++ program. No, I'm not including `.cpp` files!

This is what's happening.

main.cpp:

```
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::cout << "Hello!";
}
```

header.h:

```
#ifndef _HEADER_H
#define _HEADER_H

class Something {
public:
   printContents();
};

#endif
```

something.cpp:

```
#include "header.h"

#include <iostream>

Something::printContents() {
    cout << "This class's Contents!!";
}
```

What's happening is that I get a compiler error going: multiple definitions of some standard C function, such as `strtod`:

> g++     -o ... main.o
>   build/....main.o: In function
>   `strtod':
>
> ../MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/stdlib.h:318:
>   multiple definition of `strtod'
>
> build/..something.o:...something.cpp:(.text+0x0):
>   first defined here collect2: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

If I get rid of `#include <iostream>` in one of the two occasions and get rid of the `cout`s, it will compile. What's going on? I'm using g++ and NetBeans to compile.

I tried in the command line:

```
g++ *.h *.cpp -o program
```

and the same thing happened.

Comment: I'm surprised you even get to the linker with that code.

Comment: Can you specify more details in how you compile and link?

Comment: I ended up working it out. Fixing the code and the #ifndef fixed it all. I'm still not completely sure how the error happened. I made my own makefile and errors seem to have gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in a multi-installation of MinGW. I had one already installed, and when I got Qt on my computer, it had installed it's own MinGW. Bummer, I ported the code to my university's servers and it ran OK.

Bummer!!

Thanks everybody for the help, I will definitely follow your guidelines in the future.

Header names - no underscores
Correct return type
Real code in the forums!

Leo Bruzzaniti

Answer (score 4):

Please note that `_HEADER_H` is an illegal name in C++ user code - names beginning with the underscore and an uppercase letter are reserved for the C++ implementation. This does not normally cause noticeable problems, but when you use what may be a common name in the implementation like HEADER in this context, it well might.

Answer (score 4):

Modify,

```
Something::printContents() 
{    
  std::cout << "This class's Contents!!";
}
```

NOTE: Specify the return datatype.

Answer (score 3):

One of your problems is right here:

> I tried in the command line: g++ *.h
>   *.cpp -o program

Don't pass your header files... Try something like this:

> g++ *.cpp -o program

Comment: It should, but I'm just pointing out the error of the attempt on the command line. Other answerers have pointed out the actual code errors.

Comment: I now understand your answer! :)

Comment: While compiling headers is a pointless thing to do, it's also harmless - after all, compiling `foo.h` is exactly the same as compiling `foo.cpp` that consists of a single line `#include <foo.h>` - which is valid. I imagine it could possibly confuse the compiler if it's trying to switch between C and C++ according to file extension - I believe VC++ does that, but with gcc/g++ there is no such ambiguity, is there?

Answer (score 3):

I could not reproduce your exact problem. I get this to compile and link nicely with the following few notes:

- Add a `void` return type to the `printContents`-function (So it says `void printContents();` in the header and `void Something::printContents() {` in the implementation-file)
- Use `std::cout` rather than just `cout`. `cout` is not defined in the scope it is used
- Make sure header.h ends with a blank line
- Use `HEADER_H` rather than `_HEADER_H` (like Neil Butterworth says)

I use the command line `g++ main.cpp something.cpp` to compile.

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of problems. You shuold define the returning value of the function

```
printContents()
```

and you must write

```
std::cout
```

if you don't write

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. To everybody's attention, I did have the correct syntax, return type .. etc. I typed the question super quick. Thanks for the tips though.

Comment: Also to everybody's attention - DO NOT DO THAT! Always post REAL code using copy and paste.

Comment: Will try better in the future - I'm sure everyone has gone through the 'type for your life' stage.. My apologies.